# if values existes from given list in multiple column and counts the number of column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

i have below df

```
B      C     D         E
2      2     4         11    
11     0     5         3
12     10    1         11
5      9     7         15
```

1st i wants a unique value from whole df like below:

```
[0,1,2,3,4,5,7,9,10,11,12,15]
```

then i wants final output

```
value  value exists in number of col
0           1
1           1
2           2
3           1
4           1
5           1
7           1
9           1
10          1
11          2
12          1
15          1
```

that means each value,how many columns its available
i wants that output

Comment: What is the reason for the first unique value-step? Seems to me you could simply sort the original `df` into an array. Then multiples of the same value lie next to each other. Iterating over the array once and you can create the final output by simply counting how often a value is repeated.

Comment: thanks,can you explain in code but i also wants unique values list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using python you can do something like this:

```py
# your input df as a list of lists
df = [[2,11,12,5], [2,0,10,9], [4,5,1,7], [11,3,11,15]]

#remove duplicates in each list
dfU = [list(set(l)) for l in df]

# sort each list (not required for this approach)
for l in dfU: 
    l.sort()

# the requested unique list
flatList = [item for sublist in df for item in sublist]
uniqueList = list(set(flatList))
print(uniqueList)

# output as a list of lists
output = []
for num in uniqueList:
    cnt = 0
    for idx in range(len(dfU)):
        if dfU[idx].count(num) > 0:
            cnt+=1
    output.append([num,cnt])

print(output)
```

Side note, the `count` function is computationally expensive, so it would be better to do a linear scan along all sorted columns.

Comment: thanks for your support your code is given output number of occurence of values but i wants how many number of columns its available that value                             for ex. 11 values present 'B' & 'E' column means answer is 2 columns

Comment: yes...got exactly what I wanted...thanks for your support

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for reshape, remove duplicates by both columns and count by [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) with [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) for `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = (df.melt(value_name='value')
        .drop_duplicates()
        .groupby('value')
        .size()
        .reset_index(name='count'))
print (df1)
    value  count
0       0      1
1       1      1
2       2      2
3       3      1
4       4      1
5       5      2
6       7      1
7       9      1
8      10      1
9      11      2
10     12      1
11     15      1
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.melt(value_name='value'))
   variable  value
0         B      2
1         B     11
2         B     12
3         B      5
4         C      2
5         C      0
6         C     10
7         C      9
8         D      4
9         D      5
10        D      1
11        D      7
12        E     11
13        E      3
14        E     11
15        E     15
```

One `11` for index `14` is removed:

```
print (df.melt(value_name='value').drop_duplicates())
   variable  value
0         B      2
1         B     11
2         B     12
3         B      5
4         C      2
5         C      0
6         C     10
7         C      9
8         D      4
9         D      5
10        D      1
11        D      7
12        E     11
13        E      3
15        E     15
```

If want pure python solution:

```
from collections import Counter

L = sorted(Counter([y for x in df.T.values for y in set(x)]).items())

df1 = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['value','count'])
print (df1)
    value  count
0       0      1
1       1      1
2       2      2
3       3      1
4       4      1
5       5      2
6       7      1
7       9      1
8      10      1
9      11      2
10     12      1
11     15      1
```

Comment: i appreciate for your help but answer does not match with my output againest its gives output of total counts

Comment: @gm_datascience - Answer was changed